# Other UI that can be used in conjunction with PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, devextreme

Beside JQuery and JQuery Mobile, can this Kendo UI from Telerik be used in PhoneGap / Cordova? Similar for DexExtreme from DevExpress, can this one be used in PhoneGap / Cordova?

Thanks

Comment: you can use ALL UI frameworks that are based on HTML5, JavaScript, CSS3. some popular UI framework e.g Sencha touch, Dojo Mobile, Ionic, Twitter Bootstrap etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Telerik has KendoUI Mobile that can be used to create PhoneGap app. See [this blog](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-02-23/building_your_first_kendo_ui_mobile_phonegap_application) about building sample app with KendoUI Mobile.

DevExpress has [DevExtreme Mobile](http://js.devexpress.com/MobileDevelopment/sd) that allows to create PhoneGap app. 
This [doc article](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/VS_Integration/Packaging/?version=14_1) shows how to build PhoneGap package with DevExtreme Mobile project.